# How to use the JOIN statement in SQL

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, subquery

I'm working on an employee_data dataset which has two tables; employees and departments. I'm trying to join data from the employee table to the departments table using department_id as the primary key. It keeps giving me an error message. Please where am I missing it?

```
SELECT name AS departments_name, 
(
  SELECT name AS employees_name,
FROM `my-first-analysis.employee_data.employees`
)
FROM `my-first-analysis.employee_data.departments` 
JOIN departments ON departments.department_id = employees.department_id
```

Comment: Please don't say _an error message_ without actually posting the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
SELECT departments.name AS departments_name,
      employees.name AS employees_name,
From employees
Left JOIN departments ON departments.department_id = employees.department_id
```